# Iterate records in spark dataframe by fetching values from another dataframe

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I have 2 spark dataframes:

df1

```
+--------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|addressId           |sorted_city_ids                                          |
+--------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|AkhRMTbGbPiUnrBdSlov|[732916, 734241]                                         |
|AkhTMKHi9Ui7DHcspbfg|[724985, 725983, 725603, 728894, 728896, 728943, 729422] |
|AkhflxpBdi1tTZmmTf1w|[729103, 731732, 731736, 731738]                         |
```

df2

```
+--------------------+---------+------------------------------+-------------------+
|addressId           |city_id  |city_master_id                |dateInserted       |
+--------------------+---------+------------------------------+-------------------+
|AkhRMTbGbPiUnrBdSlov|732916   |ncLsR29SYDIeyc9aZp1cYojGvSkkWf|2021-11-04 05:30:00|
|AkhTMKHi9Ui7DHcspbfg|9361852  |mt9WV7omxa8nxD1n7yOGFDtEOTWPdq|2021-10-19 05:30:00|
|AkhflxpBdi1tTZmmTf1w|729103   |kZiy4ZeULOqqdO8yKDmsDA13RdegC2|2022-11-04 20:50:57|
|AkhflxpBdi1tTZmmTf1w|731732   |msEfdZemxa8nxD1n7yOGFDtEOTWPdq|2022-11-04 20:50:57|
|AkhflxpBdi1tTZmmTf1w|731736   |kZiy4ZeULOqqdO8yKDmsDA13RdegC2|2022-11-04 20:50:57|
|AkhflxpBdi1tTZmmTf1w|731738   |kZiy4ZeULOqqdO8yKDmsDA13RdegC2|2022-11-05 20:50:57|
```

I need to process each row in `df1`. Based on `sorted_city_ids` array column I need to do verify each city_id by fetching its corresponding `city_master_id` and `dateinserted` from `df2`. I need to check if all the city_ids in a row has same `city_master_id` and same `dateInserted` (only date and not time).

For example: In row3 of df1, I need to compare 731732, 731736 and 731738 with 729103 individually, each city_id should have same city_master_id and date as 729103(first city in array).

Expected output for row 3:

```
731732 
731738
```

731732 - as city_master_id is not matched, 731738 - as date is not matched

I dont know how to easily fetch city_master_id and dateInserted for a given city to compare with other cities..
I tried to create a map something like below
`(cityId -> List(city_master_id,date))` (Map(String, List<String,String>) using `collect.toMap()` but as data is huge from the collect() driver is failing with heap space.

Could someone please provide some leads.

Updated description for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: As per our discussion in comments**

You need to compare all cities in array with the first city based on city_master_id and dateInserted and collect city_ids of unmatching cities.

This would work:

```
df1.select("addressId", F.posexplode("sorted_city_ids").alias("index","city_id"))\
.alias("df1")\
.join(df2.withColumn("dateInserted", F.to_date(F.col("dateInserted"))).alias("df2"), [F.col("df1.addressId") == F.col("df2.addressId"),                                                                                      F.col("df1.city_id") == F.col("df2.city_id")])\
.withColumn("firstDateInserted", F.first("dateInserted").over(Window.partitionBy(F.col("df1.addressId")).orderBy("df1.index")))\
.withColumn("firstCityMasterId", F.first("city_master_id").over(Window.partitionBy(F.col("df1.addressId")).orderBy("df1.index")))\
.withColumn("unMatchingCity", F.when((F.col("city_master_id") != F.col("firstCityMasterId")) | (F.col("dateInserted") != F.col("firstDateInserted")), F.col("df1.city_id")))\
.select("df1.city_id", "df1.addressId", "df2.dateInserted", "df2.city_master_id", "unMatchingCity")\
.show(truncate=False)
```

Example:
Df1 - Df2:

[image: Df1-Df2]

Output:

[image: Output]

Get as List:

```
df1.select("addressId", F.posexplode("sorted_city_ids").alias("index","city_id"))\
.alias("df1")\
.join(df2.withColumn("dateInserted", F.to_date(F.col("dateInserted"))).alias("df2"), [F.col("df1.addressId") == F.col("df2.addressId"),                                                                                F.col("df1.city_id") == F.col("df2.city_id")])\
.withColumn("firstDateInserted", F.first("dateInserted").over(Window.partitionBy(F.col("df1.addressId")).orderBy("df1.index")))\
.withColumn("firstCityMasterId", F.first("city_master_id").over(Window.partitionBy(F.col("df1.addressId")).orderBy("df1.index")))\
.withColumn("unMatchingCity", F.when((F.col("city_master_id") != F.col("firstCityMasterId")) | (F.col("dateInserted") != F.col("firstDateInserted")), F.col("df1.city_id")))\
.groupBy("df1.addressId")\
.agg(F.first("df1.city_id").alias("city_id"),F.collect_list("unMatchingCity").alias("UnMatchedCities"), F.first("firstCityMasterId").alias("city_master_id"), F.first("dateInserted").alias("dateInserted"))\
.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Ronak Jain, its like compare city1 with city2 if matching do not do anything. if not matching return/store city2 somewhere and  continue comparing city1 with city3. Basically compare city1 and all remaining cities individually one by one.

Comment: ok, So essentially you need list of all the cities (from the array) which doesn't match with the first city, right?

Comment: yes thats correct.. I updated the description..

Comment: @Abhinay updated answer, you can change the way you want your output using the new column. Let me know if you face any issue

Comment: Thanks Ronak, I made some changes and got the required output.. Not aware of using First window function.. Accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to solve this problem with Spark SQL and python.  Please translate accordingly.

```
#
# 1 - Create sample dataframe + view
#

# required library
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

# array of tuples - data
dat1 = [
  ("AkhRMTbGbPiUnrBdSlov", [732916, 734241]),
  ("AkhTMKHi9Ui7DHcspbfg", [724985, 725983, 725603, 728894, 728896, 728943, 729422]),
  ("AkhflxpBdi1tTZmmTf1w", [729103, 731732, 731736, 731738])
]

# array of names - columns
col1 = ["address_id", "sorted_city_ids"]

# make data frame
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=dat1, schema=col1)

# make temp hive view
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp_dat1")
```

The code above creates a temporary table called "tmp_dat1".

[image]

A simple select from the table shows the sample data.

```
#
# 2 - Create sample dataframe + view
#

# required library
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

# array of tuples - data
dat2 = [
  ("AkhRMTbGbPiUnrBdSlov", "732916", "ncLsR29SYDIeyc9aZp1cYojGvSkkWf", "2021-11-04 05:30:00"),
  ("AkhTMKHi9Ui7DHcspbfg", "9361852", "mt9WV7omxa8nxD1n7yOGFDtEOTWPdq", "2021-10-1905:30:00"), 
  ("AkhflxpBdi1tTZmmTf1w", "729103", "kZiy4ZeULOqqdO8yKDmsDA13RdegC2", "2022-11-0420:50:57"), 
  ("AkhflxpBdi1tTZmmTf1w", "731732", "msEfdZemxa8nxD1n7yOGFDtEOTWPdq", "2022-11-0420:50:57"), 
  ("AkhflxpBdi1tTZmmTf1w", "731736", "kZiy4ZeULOqqdO8yKDmsDA13RdegC2", "2022-11-0420:50:57"), 
  ("AkhflxpBdi1tTZmmTf1w", "731738", "kZiy4ZeULOqqdO8yKDmsDA13RdegC2", "2022-11-0520:50:57")  
]

# array of names - columns
col2 = ["address_id", "city_id", "city_master_id", "date_inserted_str"]

# make data frame
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=dat2, schema=col2)

# convert string to date
df2 = df2.withColumn('inserted_date', to_date(substring('date_inserted_str', 1, 10), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
df2 = df2.drop("date_inserted_str")

# make temp hive view
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp_dat2")
```

The code above creates a temporary table called "tmp_dat2".

[image]

A simple select from the table shows the sample data.

Now, we need to use common table expressions since we need multiple passes at the results to do the following.

1 - explode array into rows
2 - rank rows since the first element is the driver
3 - join tables and window out first city id and first insert date
4 - calculate whether a row needs review.

I decided to treat a null value different from the current row vs the first row.

```
%sql

-- explode data
with cte1
as
(
  select address_id, explode(sorted_city_ids) as city_id from tmp_dat1
),

-- rank data
cte2
as
(
select *, row_number() over (partition by address_id order by address_id) as rid from cte1
),

-- window data
cte3
as
(
select 
  *,
  first(city_master_id) over (partition by t1.address_id order by t1.rid) as first_city_master_id,
  first(inserted_date) over (partition by t1.address_id order by t1.rid) as first_inserted_date
from 
  cte2 as t1
left join 
  tmp_dat2 as t2 on t1.city_id = t2.city_id
),

-- final data
cte4
as
(
select 
  *,
  if( 
    (ifnull(city_master_id, -1) <> ifnull(first_city_master_id, 0)) or 
    (ifnull(inserted_date, '1900-01-01') <> ifnull(first_inserted_date, '1900-01-02') )
    , 1, 0) as please_review
from cte3
)
select * from cte4 
where please_review = 0
```

If you want nulls to match (missing data from table 2), then change the default values accordingly for the isnull() function.

There are only three records that correctly follow your rules.

[image]

The rest need to be fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I will do the task in four steps.

## Build Data

```scala
case class DF1(id: String, cities: Vector[Int])

case class DF2(id: Int, master: String, timestamp: Timestamp)

val df1 = ss.createDataFrame(
  Vector(
    DF1("Address1", Vector(1, 2)),    // Verified
    DF1("Address2", Vector(1, 2, 3)), // Verified (3: The same day, different time)
    DF1("Address3", Vector(1, 2, 4)), // Not verified (4: Different day)
    DF1("Address4", Vector(1, 2, 5)), // Not verified (5: Different master)
  )
)

val df2 = ss.createDataFrame(
  Vector(
    DF2(1, "1", Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now())),
    DF2(2, "1", Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now())),
    DF2(3, "1", Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(1))),
    DF2(4, "1", Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(1))),
    DF2(5, "2", Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now())),
  )
)
```

df1:

```
+--------+---------+
|      id|   cities|
+--------+---------+
|Address1|   [1, 2]|
|Address2|[1, 2, 3]|
|Address3|[1, 2, 4]|
|Address4|[1, 2, 5]|
+--------+---------+
```

df2:

```
+---+------+--------------------+
| id|master|           timestamp|
+---+------+--------------------+
|  1|     1|2023-02-27 13:53:...|
|  2|     1|2023-02-27 13:53:...|
|  3|     1|2023-02-27 13:53:...|
|  4|     1|2023-02-28 13:53:...|
|  5|     2|2023-02-27 13:53:...|
+---+------+--------------------+
```

## Preprocess Data

It is not possible to iterate on cities, but we can create a row for each city, and do the rest of the process on each row, then aggregate the results.

```scala
val df1Preprocessed = df1.select(col("id"), explode(col("cities")) as "cityId")
```

We don't need time, so we should transform timestamp to date.

```scala
val df2Preprocessed = df2.withColumn("date", to_date(col("timestamp")))
```

df1Preprocessed:

```
+--------+------+
|      id|cityId|
+--------+------+
|Address1|     1|
|Address1|     2|
|Address2|     1|
|Address2|     2|
|Address2|     3|
|Address3|     1|
|Address3|     2|
|Address3|     4|
|Address4|     1|
|Address4|     2|
|Address4|     5|
+--------+------+
```

df2Preprocessed:

```
+---+------+--------------------+----------+
| id|master|           timestamp|      date|
+---+------+--------------------+----------+
|  1|     1|2023-02-27 14:01:...|2023-02-27|
|  2|     1|2023-02-27 14:01:...|2023-02-27|
|  3|     1|2023-02-27 14:01:...|2023-02-27|
|  4|     1|2023-02-28 14:01:...|2023-02-28|
|  5|     2|2023-02-27 14:01:...|2023-02-27|
+---+------+--------------------+----------+
```

## Join Preprocessed Data and Create Condition Parameters

```scala
val joinedDF = df1Preprocessed
  .as("df1")
  .join(df2Preprocessed.as("df2"), col("df1.cityId") === col("df2.id"))
  .groupBy("df1.id")
  .agg(
    min(col("df2.master")) as "minMaster",
    max(col("df2.master")) as "maxMaster",
    min(col("df2.date")) as "minDate",
    max(col("df2.date")) as "maxDate",
  )
```

joinedDF:

```
+--------+---------+---------+----------+----------+
|      id|minMaster|maxMaster|   minDate|   maxDate|
+--------+---------+---------+----------+----------+
|Address1|        1|        1|2023-02-27|2023-02-27|
|Address2|        1|        1|2023-02-27|2023-02-27|
|Address3|        1|        1|2023-02-27|2023-02-28|
|Address4|        1|        2|2023-02-27|2023-02-27|
+--------+---------+---------+----------+----------+
```

## Verify

Now, it is pretty straightforward to verify data. if min and max of master are equal, all cities for the address have the same master, and the same argument is also true for date.

```scala
val verifyDF = joinedDF
  .select(
    col("id"),
    col("minMaster") === col("maxMaster") && col("minDate") === col("maxDate") as "verified"
  )
```

verifyDF:

```
+--------+--------+
|      id|verified|
+--------+--------+
|Address1|    true|
|Address2|    true|
|Address3|   false|
|Address4|   false|
+--------+--------+
```

Comment: hi @Saeid Dadkhah, I need to find out the cities which doesnt meet the criteria, meaning all the cities should for a given address id should have same city_master_id and date as the first city in the row. if not matching get all the remaining cities in the list except first city. Above code works if there are only cities in the array.. but there can be n no.of cities for a address id.

Comment: @Abhinay Do you mean if element1 is not such that it's corresponding elements match with other peers, we need to try with element2 ?